# Managing a Project Having Two Different Code Versions in Repo

Tags: android, eclipse, repository, team-explorer-everywhere, azure-devops

I am new to managing a project having different versions (eh branched revs.?) inside a Repository.

I have a free tier account on visual studio online and an Android project having two different code revisions.

My problem is that I have to work on any one of the versions anytime intermittently.
So, is there a way I can make separate check-in areas (I think I should branch it) but I am not aware of the branch'ing concept. Would require some step-by-step tut on that.

Currently, I have 2 different changesets storing those two different versions and while checking-in resolving conflicts is a pain_in_the_a** :/ I am using Team explorer plugin in eclipse.

Any help is appreciated. 

TIA

Comment: revisions = versions? You're managing two different versions in production at the same time? Also, are you using Git of TFVC (the default) for your source control?

Comment: @AndrewClear Thanks for replying. Yep, I have two different versions of the same code; it is for 2 different vendors. I am using the free account for visual studio online and its Eclipse plugin (team explorer).

Answer (score 0):

[the below assumes you're using TFVC]

You want to use branches so that you can maintain different versions of your code. Go here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668955.aspx

And read the entire thing. Section 3, Branch for Maintenance is probably your best general strategy. Here's a helpful tutorial on creating branches with Team Explorer Everywhere:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490758(v=vs.100).aspx

That should be enough to get you started. As a philosophical side note, always attempt to minimize the number of branches (published variety, for the Git folks) as they add complexity.